# HTML multiple page form showing hidding sections preserving form data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

Here's my problem I want to have a form that's like 25 pages so i would like to avoid having one huge page to scroll forever.

Ideally i would like to load external html files at runtime while preserving form data until the user submits it.

I made an initial page with a nice cool menu when the user clicks on a link,
 i would like to replace the content with content from another html file.

I tried using javascript function and replacing with an iframe but it's not quite working the way i want it to. With enough debugging I could get it to work but it seems like there must be a better way to go about this...

Since sometimes problems that seem very difficult are sometimes much easier with another approach, so please enlighten me.

```
function ContentMap()
{
    var __contentMap = [];
    var __index = 0;
    this.length  = function()
    {
        return __contentMap.length;
    }
    this.addContentMap = function(htmlContent)
    {
        __contentMap.push(htmlContent);
        __index++;
        console.log(htmlContent["id"]);
    }
    this.getContentMap = function(contentId)
    {
        for(q=0;q<__contentMap.length;q++)
        {
            if(contentId.localeCompare(__contentMap[q].id)==0)
            {
                return _contentMap[q];  
            }
        }
    }
    this.getPreviousMap = function()
    {
        if(this.length()>0&&index>0)
        {
            index--;
            return _contentMap[index];  
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
var contentMap = new ContentMap();
function replaceContent(contentId,replacementId)
{
    citem = document.getElementById(contentId);
    for(__i=0;__i<citem.childNodes.length;__i++)
    {
        contentMap.addContentMap(citem.childNodes.item(__i));
        citem.removeChild(citem.childNodes.item(__i));
    }
    iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src",replacementId);
    iframe.style.width = document.getElementById(contentId).width;
    iframe.style.height = document.getElementById(contentId).height;
    citem.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use PHP?

Comment: You could use javascript to hold the previous values but this would mean having many variables or a big array **or** you could use local storage to hold this data while changing pages content of navigating to different pages/directories on your website. How to use local storage- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp This could all depend on the form, are the questions going to be different depending on the answer to another or are the questions set...

Comment: can you try to append the data from each of the pages into a javascript object whenever you move to the next page, and finally while submiting the form, post this object..

Comment: @shridhar yes i could use PHP if i wanted to, what do you suggest?

Comment: @NewToJS Yes access to storage would also be fine i was thinking about just doing something like onClick=('containerId','replaceWithUrl') just have the function store the html like this is what i was fooling around with almost works but the iframe is sent to the bottom of the screen and for some reason gets the size not from the containerId sent to the function but the actual node cliked size ??? WT% see code bellow

Answer (score 0):

```
i am not sure whether this is the solution you need. 

    form1.php
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        This is first form..
        <input type="submit" name="form_2" value="submit form1">
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['form_2'])) {
            include("form2.html");
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

form2.php

```
<html>
This is second form.
</html>
```

This will display second form on the same page but you have to css to show only form2

Comment: If this is not the solution you are looking for just let me know.

Comment: this could be the ticket do you think using the back button woud work?

Comment: On the coded i added the childNodes are not removed??? the form is loaded in the iframe but at the bottom of the screen?? no debug errors

Comment: after clicking on back button the jquery will hide form2 and display only content of form1.